# How to parse a command output in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, parsing

Can anyone please suggest me that how can I parse the below command output and store particular value in a variable.

**sestatus**

This is the output of that command

```
SELinux status:                 enabled  
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux  
Current mode:                   enforcing  
Mode from config file:          enforcing  
Policy version:                 24  
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

Here I want to store **"enforcing"** of Current mode: in a variable.

Can anyone please suggest me.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Thanks All...all answers were useful.

Answer (score 13):

you can use cut or sed, anyone implementation is good enough to use,

```
[root@giam20 ~]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
[root@giam20 ~]# variable=`sestatus | grep 'Current mode'|cut -f2 -d ":"`
[root@giam20 ~]# echo $variable
enforcing
[root@giam20 ~]#
```

this is simple to write than above.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `sed`:

```
variable=$(the_command | sed -n 's/Current mode: \(.*\)/\1/p')
```

The `$(cmd)` syntax is called [command substituion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html), the statement will being expanded by the output of `cmd`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use awk:

```
variable=`sestatus | awk '/Current mode:/ {print $3}'`
```